# Is multiple tag formatting an intentional feature?

Tags: support, tags, markdown

[tag](/questions/tagged/tag) [formatting](/questions/tagged/formatting) is [fun](/questions/tagged/fun).

[combinations](/questions/tagged/combinations) of [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) is [awesome](/questions/tagged/awesome)!

But to have [multiple+combinations](/questions/tagged/multiple%2bcombinations) of [awesome+tags](/questions/tagged/awesome%2btags) is [beyondcompare](/questions/tagged/beyondcompare)!

But is this an intentional [formatting+feature](/questions/tagged/formatting%2bfeature)? Or simply a [formatting+side-effect](/questions/tagged/formatting%2bside-effect)?

Will [future+updates](/questions/tagged/future%2bupdates) [remove](/questions/tagged/remove) this [awesome+feature](/questions/tagged/awesome%2bfeature)?

Or should I create a [formatting+multiple+tags+feature-request](/questions/tagged/formatting%2bmultiple%2btags%2bfeature-request)?

Comment: You can even do `+or+` in there to get OR logic. I had tested this on Gaming, but withdrew it thinking that it's too much of a hassle to worry about.

Comment: 20k ability: Post more than two `[tag:]` s  in a post

Comment: @Grace Neat! I guess my main question is: Can I use this, say on a tag wiki page, and expect it to work in the future?

Comment: I thought about that when I did the test on Gaming. You know what I concluded? It looks **ABSOLUTELY HORRENDOUS**, and isn't intuitive to know what it does. I think it's more useful to just make compound logic strings as pure hyperlinks. Tag formatting is awesome... but I don't think we need to try and accomodate all the logic to make them complex. I think of it as an easter egg more than anything I'll ever use.

Comment: @Grace: yeah. It was their appearance that made me think it was only a side effect.

Answer (score 1):

[support+tags+markdown](/questions/tagged/support%2btags%2bmarkdown)